# Rails & Groupdate gem to find users with more than X videos per month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arel

Users in my Rails app make videos. I'm using the Groupdate gem to get the monthly active users (meaning the number of user who made more than 1 video in the month):

`Video.group_by_month(:created_at).count("DISTINCT user_id")`

which returns something like this:

```
{
 Mon, 01 Aug 2022=>116,
 Thu, 01 Sep 2022=>101,
 Sat, 01 Oct 2022=>109,
 Tue, 01 Nov 2022=>153,
 Thu, 01 Dec 2022=>104
}
```

Now I want to get the number of user who made more than X videos, grouped by month as before.

How do I do that?

Comment: @engineersmnky Not quite. That does something but not what I need. Thanks for the direction though. Looking at 'having' now.

Comment: How about this `Video.group_by_month(:created_at).where(user_id: Video.select(:user_id).group(:user_id).having(Video.arel_table[:user_id].count.gt(x))).count("DISTINCT user_id")`